# Why can some ASCII characters not be expressed in the form '\uXXXX' in Java source code?

Tags: java

I stumbled over this (again) today:

```
class Test {
    char ok = '\n';
    char okAsWell = '\u000B';
    char error = '\u000A';
}
```

It does not compile:

> Invalid character constant in line 4.

The compiler seems to insist that I write '\n' instead. I see no reason for this, yet it's *very* annoying.

Is there a logical explanation why characters that have a special notation (like `\t`, `\n`, `\r`) *must* be expressed in that form in Java source?

Comment: You can replace all the source in your code with `\uXXXX` sequences to make it unreadable, but it will compile fine as it converts all these to the text before compiling.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Unicode characters are replaced by their value, so your line is replaced by the compiler with:

```
char error = '
';
```

which is not a valid Java statement.

This is dictated by the [Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code unit (§3.1) of the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other characters unchanged. Representing supplementary characters requires two consecutive Unicode escapes. This translation step results in a sequence of Unicode input characters.

This can lead to surprising stuff, for example, this is a valid Java program (it contains hidden unicode characters) - [courtesy of Peter Lawrey](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++) {
        if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h)) {
            System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good to know. So if I use `System.out.print("Hello ");//\u000ASystem.out.println("World");` it prints "Hello World" even if second print is teoreticly in comment:D

Comment: You were first, I believe, so I accepted this one :) Although that perfectly explains the cause behind it, I'm still curious why the language creators thought that early expansion was a good idea. It still strikes me as a big WTF.

Comment: @Durandal Doing that enables you to use characters that can't be represented in the charset of the source file (not that it has ever happen to me!).

Answer (score 23):

**Unicode escape sequences like `\u000a` are replaced** by the actual characters they represent before the Java compiler does anything else with the source code. And so, your program eventually ends up at

```
char ch = '
';
```

So the `\u000a` in your source code is replaced internally by a linefeed character. Note that this happens before the compiler actually reads and interprets your source code.

Referring to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4):

> It is a compile-time error for a **line terminator** (§3.4) to appear after the opening ' and before the closing '.

And as well all know by heart, `\n` is a [line terminator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4), quoting:

```
 LineTerminator:
    the ASCII LF character, also known as "newline"
    the ASCII CR character, also known as "return"
    the ASCII CR character followed by the ASCII LF character
```

Other symbols that could cause problems are `\`, `'` and `"` for example.

Comment: The program looks like what?

Comment: There seem to be a lot more than 3: \u0027 (') \u005c (\\) also create havoc. \u0034 (") breaks String literals.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason is that `\uXXXX` sequences are expanded when the code is being parsed, see [JLS §3.2. Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2).

Answer (score 4):

It is described in 3.3. Unicode Escapes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html. Javac first finds \uxxxx sequences in .java and replaces them with real characters then compiles. In case of

```
char error = '\u000A';
```

\u000A will be replace with `newline` character code (10) and the actual text will be

```
char error = '
';
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler treats them the same as unescaped text.

This is valid code:

```
 class \u00C9 {}
```