# How unicode characters are read in java comments

Tags: java, unicode

```
class Why
{
    public static void main(String[]s)
    {
        String st2="A";
        System.out.println(st2);
        // String st4="MN3444\u000ar4t4";
        System.out.println(st4);

    }
}
```

please compile the above code, i am getting the error in the comment line.

I am unable to understand this behaviour of the compiler, 
and what does this error mean ?

Comment: What does compiler say?

Comment: Wow! This looks like a JDK issue.

Comment: someone started this on a facebook group and explained something related to UNICODE characters, but they could not explain why compiler reads something in comment ..
also if u re[place this by multi line comment ( /* */) , it is not read by compiler,

@kugathasan : bro just compile this and you will get to know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can some ASCII characters not be expressed in the form '\uXXXX' in Java source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275945/why-can-some-ascii-characters-not-be-expressed-in-the-form-uxxxx-in-java-sour)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before compilation every Unicode character is replaced by its value and since `\u000a` represents new line code

```
// String st4="MN3444\u000ar4t4";
```

is same as this code (notice that text after `\u000a` will be moved to new line, which means it will no longer be part of commented)

```
// String st4="MN3444
r4t4";
```

You can test it with

```
//\u000a;System.out.println("hello comment");
```

which is equal to

```
//
System.out.println("hello comment");
```

and will give you as result output: `hello comment`

Comment: agreed with the concept of unicode bro, but how come the compiler is reading code from the comment ?

Comment: @Gagan93 well you see, point is that after translating `\u000a` to its  value your code after `\u000a` will not be in comment any more, but in separate line.

Comment: @Gagan93 Take a look at question I suggested as possible duplicate (finally found it). There should be few good answers that could help you better understand this topic.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the ASCII table for `\u000a`, we see that that is a newline. So I think that the compiler replaces inside the comment the ASCII escapes by the corresponding value. Since this is a newline, the code looks like this:

```
// String st4="MN3444
r4t4";
```

That is why the compiler says: "*String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote*".

So, that explains as well why it works for multiline comments:

/* String st4="MN3444\u000ar4t4"; */

Gets resolved to:

```
   /* String st4="MN3444
r4t4"; */
```

which is a fine comment.

---

The behavior is defined: [JLS §3.2. Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2)

> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of
>   tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are
>   applied in turn:
>
> A translation of Unicode escapes (§3.3) in the raw stream of Unicode
>   characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape of
>   the form \uxxxx, where xxxx is a hexadecimal value, represents the
>   UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is xxxx. This translation step allows
>   any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.

---

Just as a test case, this compiles fine :)

```
\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u006c\u006e\u0028\u0022\u0054\u0068\u0069\u0073\u0020\u0069\u0073\u0020\u0063\u006f\u006f\u006c\u0021\u0022\u0029\u003b
```